# Elevate the weight of browsing history in Google Chrome's autocomplete

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Google Chrome has the feature of auto-completing web addresses while you type them in the address bar.

Alas, it gives absurdly more weight to Google's own auto-suggest v.s. my own browsing history, which seems a bit foolish - if I regularly (i.e. twice a week) check a certain website with the keywords "foo bar ponies" in its url, it is reasonable to expect that I will want to visit that site again and not other sites.

While a bit subjective, to the very least I would expect such URLs to be in the list Chrome suggests, even if not at the top.

Is there some plugin/secret option that alters the default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely disable Google's auto-complete, leaving only your own by going to *Options* and unchecking "Use a suggestion service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar".

Comment: I would've preferred a solution that still takes into account auto-suggest (i.e. if no match found in history then auto-suggest), but it seems that disabling it is currently the only sensible option... Thanks!