# Edit address bar autocomplete behaviour in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm finding the autocomplete behaviour a bit annoying for websites that have similar urls. My normal way of going to a website which I use often is to type in the first character and press enter. So for example, when I type 'f' the address bar would autocomplete it to 'facebook.com'.

However a few of the websites which I visit often are similar enough that I have to type a number of characters to let Chrome know which one I want to use. For example, if I type 't', it might autocomplete to 'twitter.com', but if I want to go to 'twitch.tv' I have to type out 'twitc' before it correctly autocompletes.

Is there a way to adjust the way this works, or are there any extensions that would let me do so?
I would prefer it if typing one character autocompletes to the first most visited site, typing two autocompletes to the second, and so on.

Comment: I feel the same way. It annoys me every day. Here is a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/141816/elevate-the-weight-of-browsing-history-in-google-chromes-autocomplete?rq=1